# Java Play Facebook Authenticate

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, playframework, oauth-2.0

I recently managed to implement sign-in with Twitter using OAuth, but I can't seem to find any good up-to-date information on how to implement Facebook sign-in with Play 2.5.x for **Java**.

The Twitter implementation I did was done without plugins, and I keep hearing that Facebook should be easier with OAuth2, but I haven't found examples to prove this claim. All that I found is some plugins, but they are lacking proper documentation on how to implement it.

Has anybody successfully implemented this with Play 2.5? Would you mind writing down some guidelines on how to approach this, and perhaps some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use 3rd part libraries then try https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4.

It has the java and scala demos:

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-scala-demo

Or you can look at the source to manage how it works with the Facebook auth.

Here is the source of the FacebookClient, you can start digging from there: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-oauth/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oauth/client/FacebookClient.java

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and decided to go with a plugin instead, went with Facebook4j which seems to work ok.